# How to create buffer from audio chunks in React Native?

Tags: react-native, audio, udp

I have a device, which can't use WebRTC. For real time audio streaming i am using udp socket. This socket is sending audio chunks. I need to create a playable buffer which can append chunks dynamically, any thoughts about that?

I tried to join this chunks and than save it to file and play, but it is not real time at all :(

```js
this.audioSocket.on('message', (data, rinfo) => {
}
```

Here we get data (Uint8Array) from our device

Is there any playable memory buffer?

Comment: what audio player are you using ?  what is reading the buffer and rendering audio ?   your last sentence is unclear ... any memory buffer is playable

Comment: Now, i am just play a file created by joining few chunks, and use for it - react-native-sound, i need to create buffer which i can play back at the same time as append new chunks

Comment: as a learning exercise I strongly suggest you just roll up your sleeves and write your own function to do this ... probably just as fast and more productive for you rather than spending days searching for some api call which may or may not do what you need ... and if you write your own you will learn more than just plugging in some api call ... appending data to a buffer is very doable yourself